# Create a new column in a dataframe out of previous rows from a factor variable

Tags: r

Given a dataframe like this:

```
game     team
zap.che  zap
zap.che  che
zap.che  zap
zap.che  zap
zap.che  che
bar.var  bar
bar.var  var
bar.var  var
bar.var  bar
bar.var  bar
```

I'd like to add another new column, being my desired outcome something like this:

```
game     team    poss
zap.che  zap     1
zap.che  che     1
zap.che  zap     2
zap.che  zap     2
zap.che  che     2
bar.var  bar     1
bar.var  var     1
bar.var  var     1
bar.var  bar     2
bar.var  bar     2
```

My purposes are: 
a) assign the same value to all the consecutive occurrences of the same value in "team" column
b) count all the wrapped "team" values in "poss" column (1,2,3 and so on)
c) once in "game" column the value changes, restart the same process

Comment: Not clear about the logic.  Why the number is changing only for certain values

Comment: The logic is the following:
for example, everytime a value on "team" column (e.g."zap") shows up, we count it as a new "poss" occurrence (1,2,3,..) except when "zap" appears consecutively (in this case we consider this occurrence belongs to the same "poss" value).
Once "game" value changes, "poss" count restarts following the same criteria.

Comment: But, in the `bar.var`, there is no 'zap'

Comment: As I said before, once "game" value changes "poss" count restarts following same criteria, now with "bar" or "var"

Comment: @teogi  Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a new column representing `row_number()` of the dataframe,  `group_by` `game` and `team` and increment the count when `diff`erence between consecutive `row` is more than 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(game, team) %>%
  mutate(poss = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(row) > 1)))%>%
  select(-row)

#   game    team   poss
#   <fct>   <fct> <int>
# 1 zap.che zap       1
# 2 zap.che che       1
# 3 zap.che zap       2
# 4 zap.che zap       2
# 5 zap.che che       2
# 6 bar.var bar       1
# 7 bar.var var       1
# 8 bar.var var       1
# 9 bar.var bar       2
#10 bar.var bar       2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ronak!

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to group by 'game', then get the run-length-id based on the first level of 'team' and `fill` the `NA` elements with the previous non-NA elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(game = factor(game, levels = unique(game))) %>%
    mutate(poss = as.integer(factor(rleid(team != first(team)) *
          NA^(team != first(team))))) %>% 
   fill(poss)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   game [2]
#   game    team   poss
#   <fct>   <chr> <int>
# 1 zap.che zap       1
# 2 zap.che che       1
# 3 zap.che zap       2
# 4 zap.che zap       2
# 5 zap.che che       2
# 6 bar.var bar       1
# 7 bar.var var       1
# 8 bar.var var       1
# 9 bar.var bar       2
#10 bar.var bar       2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(game = c("zap.che", "zap.che", "zap.che", "zap.che", 
"zap.che", "bar.var", "bar.var", "bar.var", "bar.var", "bar.var"
), team = c("zap", "che", "zap", "zap", "che", "bar", "var", 
"var", "bar", "bar")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```